# Why does the ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error occur when opening a file located in Google Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloudflare

I have several apps that work with Google Storage. One of these apps has stopped displaying images in its interface.

The application code has nothing to do with it - all files are uploaded into GS successfully.

The problem is on the Cloudflare side or somewhere near it. Although all other applications are configured identically.

In Cloudflare, all apps have a similar entry:

```
CNAME   files   c.storage.googleapis.com   TTL Auto   Proxied
```

Only the domain changes, of course.

And only one domain gets an error when using a URL with HTTPS: `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

If replace HTTPS with HTTP, then the file will be opened.

What could be the problem, since I use the same settings everywhere in Cloudflare?

Comment: Well, of course, if you use HTTP you won't get any certificate errors, because it won't use certificates. Check the certificate of that specific domain that fails. There is something wrong with it. Either its too old that it only supports old versions of ssl or private key and cert don't match

Comment: @derpirscher What exactly do I need to check? The nginx server doesn't take part in this. Cloudflare is configured "flexible" in SSL/TLS (just like other applications in Cloudflare). In the "Edge Certificates" tab the settings are also identical.

Comment: I have no experience with cloudflare, so I can't help you there. But the certificate for that particular domain obviously has some issues. How did you obtain it? Maybe you can generate a new one and replace the existing one?

Comment: @derpirscher I did not touch the certificate at all. It is provided by Cloudflare when Proxy is enabled in their panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It was necessary to enable this option:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have to disable the Universal Certificate OR may be turn the CNAME to grey clouded on Cloudflare.

Apparently Cloudflare will get the SSL upto single level sub-domains only i.e. `sub.domain.tld` but the GCS domain is beyond that. I had the same issue for one of my subdomains "sub2.sub.domain.tld" and I ended up changing it to `sub2-sub.domain.tld` but I don't think that's possible in your case.

[Here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/sub-domain-with-www-get-err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch/2420/6?u=dharmaraj) is the link to Cloudflare forums for the same

[image]

So if you want to use their Universal SSL you'll have to upgrade your plan to Business.